# Trying to get Filepath with Open Dialog

Tags: c#, web-applications, file-io, epplus

I am currently making a web application using epPlus along with it to save the current database to an excel file.  That part is easy and working, but what I'm trying to do is create a pop up dialog box that will allow the client to select the directory they want to save the excel file to.  Then use the path they've given me and use the SaveAs function in epPlus with the path they have selected.

The question is how do I go about getting the dialog box to work and getting the path?  I've tried using Response and I can't seem to get that working.  The problem is that the excel file is only an object until save is done, and I need the path to do the save.  Ideas?  here's my code.

```
    protected void OnbtnSaveExcelFileClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String FileName = "GamingRecords";
        String FilePath = @"C:\....\";
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
        try
        {
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(flUploadLink.FileContent))
            {

                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Games to Date - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                worksheet.DefaultRowHeight = 22;

                var headers = new[] { Constants.GameTitle, Constants.GameGenre, Constants.Price, Constants.Quantity };
                for (var i = 1; i < headers.Count() + 1; i++)
                    worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value = headers[i - 1];
                var game = new GameClass();
                var list = game.FetchAll();
                var rowNumber = 2;
                foreach (var t in list)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = t.GameTitle;
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = t.GameGenre;
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = t.Price;
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = t.Quantity;
                    rowNumber++;
                }
                for (var i = 1; i < worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; i++)
                    worksheet.Column(i).AutoFit();

                package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Games on Record";
                package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Kirk Rudzinski";
                package.Workbook.Properties.Company = "Logistics+";
                package.Save();
                litExcelError.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        { litExcelError.Text = "Please close the file to make modifications"; }
    }
```

Comment: There is no way for you to choose where the file will be saved on the client's computer.

Comment: No, I want a dialog box to appear and them choose where the file will be saved.  I probably just explained myself poorly I apologize!

Comment: You also cannot do that, the client will choose by itself where the file will be saved, you have absolutely no control over that. The browser will put the file in the user's default download folder.

Comment: Alright I believe that helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, just to clarify I figured out how to do it the way I was trying.  For reference in case anyone runs into an error like this here is the code!

```
    protected void OnbtnSaveExcelFileClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(flUploadLink.FileContent))
            {

                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Games to Date - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                worksheet.DefaultRowHeight = 22;

                var headers = new[] { Constants.GameTitle, Constants.GameGenre, Constants.Price, Constants.Quantity };
                for (var i = 1; i < headers.Count() + 1; i++)
                    worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value = headers[i - 1];

                int rowNumber = 2;
                foreach (GridViewRow row in grdGamingTable.Rows)
                {
                    var index = row.RowIndex; 
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value = grdGamingTable.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value = grdGamingTable.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value = Convert.ToInt16(grdGamingTable.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text);
                    worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value = Convert.ToInt16(grdGamingTable.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text);
                    rowNumber++;
                }


                for (var i = 1; i < worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; i++)
                    worksheet.Column(i).AutoFit();

                package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Games on Record";
                package.Save();
                litExcelError.Visible = false;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=GameRecords.xlsx");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        { litExcelError.Text = "Please close the file to make modifications"; }
    }
```